# iOS youtube embed player doesn't play video on click on the red button

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube

Everything's on the title.

I have a Youtube player on an HTML website. On IOS devices, the video won't play when i tap on the red "play" button. It will play if  I touch the preview image only !

You can try it here, its even on the Youtube API page, its quite huge : 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

The code I use :

```
var _player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: id,
        playerVars: {
            controls:1,
            showinfo:0,
            modestbranding: 1
        },
        events: {
          'onReady': _onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': _onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
```

Is it a common bug ? Or is it fixable ? Thanks for help !!

Comment: I am encountering the same issue; this also happens on my Android Tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab). The iOS Version of the iPad is 8 and the Android  Version is 4.42. I'm pretty sure that this problem did not occur a little while back so this might be a YouTube issue which cannot be fixed on user side.

Comment: I just found out, that the play button does not work when you state "controls=1" or in your case "controls: 1" in the embed parameters; using "controls=0" allows you to click the play button. This seems to be an issue on YouTube's side.

Comment: yeah im sure it was working before too. Unfortunately I can't disable controls.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, ugly at best, is to click on the bottom of the embed, in the area where controls appear. That area does respond to clicks both in iOS and Android, even though the rest of the area does not respond.